# How to calculate the intercept of an indifference curve in an Edgeworth box?

Tags: microeconomics, free-trade, exchange

Consider an exchange economy with two goods (Good 1 and 2) and two individuals ($A$ and $B$):

- $A$'s utility function is $u_A(x_{A_1}, x_{A_2}) = 2x_{A_1} + 5x_{A_2}$
- $B$'s utility function is $u_B(x_{B_1}, x_{B_2}) = 3x_{B_1} + 7x_{B_2}$
- $A$'s initial endowment is $(\omega_{A_1}, \omega_{A_2}) = (4, 6)$
- $B$'s initial endowment is $(\omega_{B_1}, \omega_{B_2}) = (10, 2)$

The core condition requires:

$$
2x_{A_1} + 5x_{A_2} \geq 2\omega_{A_1} + 5\omega_{A_2} = 2 \times 4 + 5 \times 6 = 38
$$

and

$$
3x_{B_1} + 7x_{B_2} \geq 3\omega_{B_1} + 7\omega_{B_2} = 3 \times 10 + 7 \times 2 = 44
$$

The line with  equation $2x_{A_1} + 5x_{A_2} = 38$ hits the left boundary at:

$$
(x_{A_1}, x_{A_2}) = (0,38/5), ~~~~(x_{B_1}, x_{B_2}) = (14, 2/5)
$$

The line with equation $3x_{B_1} + 7x_{B_2} = 44$ hits the left boundary at:

$$ 
(x_{A_1}, x_{A_2}) = (0,54/7) ~~~ (x_{B_1}, x_{B_2}) = (14, 2/7)
$$

I don't understand how these intercepts have been calculated.

I've used the MRS and endowment point to calculate the $(x_{A_1}, x_{A_2})$
intercepts correctly:

$$x_{A_2} = -\frac{2}{5}x_{A_1} + \frac{38}{5}$$

But get an incorrect $(x_{B_1}, x_{B_2})$ intercept:

$$
x_{A_1} = 14, ~~ x_{A_2} = 2 
$$

Please can someone enlighten me? No worries if you can't.

Alex

Answer (score 1):

In an edgeworth box model the total amount of goods must be constant. In your problem this translates to

\begin{eqnarray}
x_{A_1} + x_{B_1} &=& \omega_{A_1} + \omega_{B_1} = 10 + 4 = 14 \tag{1}\\
x_{A_2} + x_{B_2} &=& \omega_{A_2} + \omega_{B_2} = 6 + 2 = 8 \tag{2}\\
\end{eqnarray}

So let's consider the first intercept

$$
(x_{A_1}, x_{A_2}) = (0, 38/5) \tag{3}
$$

which you properly derived. If you replace these values in Eq. (1) you get

$$
0 + x_{B_1} = 14 ~~~\Rightarrow~~~ x_{B_1} = 14 \tag{4}
$$

and if you replace in Eq. (2) you get

$$
\frac{38}{5} + x_{B_2} = 8 ~~~\Rightarrow~~~ x_{B_2} = \frac{2}{5} \tag{5}
$$

So there you have it

$$
(x_{A_1}, x_{A_2}) = (0,38/5), ~~~(x_{B_1}, x_{B_2}) = (14,2/5)
$$

You can do the same for the other intercept, I will leave that for you to complete

Answer (score 1):

We are given the following two-consumer, two-goods pure exchange economy.

$u_1(x_1,y_1)=2x_1+5y_1$,
$u_2(x_2,y_2)=3x_2+7y_2$

$\omega_1=(\omega_1^X,\omega_1^Y)=(4,6)$ and $\omega_2=(\omega_2^X,\omega_2^Y)=(10,2)$

Set of feasible allocations is given by:

$\mathcal{F}=\{((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))\in\mathbb{R}^2_+\times\mathbb{R}^2_+|x_1+x_2=14 \ \wedge \ y_1+y_2=8\}$

Set of Pareto efficient allocations is given by:

$\mathcal{P}=\{((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))\in\mathcal{F}|x_1=0 \ \vee \ y_1 = 8\}$

Core is the set of efficient allocations that satisfy the property that both the individuals get at least as much satisfaction as their respective endowments. Observing the graph, we get the core as:

\begin{eqnarray*} \mathcal{C} & = & \left\{((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))\in\mathcal{P}|2x_1+5y_1\geq 38 \ \wedge \ 3x_2+7y_2\geq 44\right\} \\ & = & \left\{((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))\in\mathcal{P}|x_1=0 \ \wedge \ \frac{38}{5}\leq y_1 \leq \frac{54}{7}\right\} \end{eqnarray*}

Here is the picture:
[image]